# STM32 HAL VS dual 595 driven 7 segment display

Tags: stm32, embedded, 7segmentdisplay, nucleo, 74hc595

I got [this](https://www.electroschematics.com/getting-started-with-the-arduino-multifunction-shield/) arduino shield with four 7 segment display what I'm trying to make work with STM32 nucleo. The displays are driven with two 74HC595 shift registers.

I wrote the following code to control it, but somehow it doesn't work, always shows the same pattern whatever I modify in the array.

```
int digits[16] = {1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,0}; 
while (1) {
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(STCP_GPIO_Port, STCP_Pin, GPIO_PIN_RESET);
    for(int i=0;i>=15;i--) {
        HAL_GPIO_WritePin(SHCP_GPIO_Port, SHCP_Pin, GPIO_PIN_RESET);
        if(digits[i]==1) {
            HAL_GPIO_WritePin(DS_GPIO_Port, DS_Pin, GPIO_PIN_SET);
        }else {
            HAL_GPIO_WritePin(DS_GPIO_Port, DS_Pin, GPIO_PIN_RESET);
        }
        HAL_GPIO_WritePin(SHCP_GPIO_Port, SHCP_Pin, GPIO_PIN_SET);
    }
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(STCP_GPIO_Port, STCP_Pin, GPIO_PIN_SET);

}
```

SHCP: Shift register clock

STCP: Storage register Clock

DS: Data

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your for loop has an error. It would try to count backwards from 0 until it is larger than 14. My rough estimate is that it takes about 2^31 loops until the count reaches largest negative number and rolls back to largest positive number before the for loop exits.

Comment: Indeed, that was the solution. Thank you!